About convergence on Sobolev Spaces
I am new to Sobolev spaces and am trying to understand convergence. I came across this question in some course notes but couldn't find an example. If anyone could please help me with a hint, it would be greatly appreciated!
Provide an example of a sequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $W_\alpha(\Omega)$ and a function $u \in W_\alpha(\Omega)$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$,$\delta^\alpha u_n \not\to \delta^\alpha u$ in $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ for some open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ and some multi index $\alpha$.
Edit
I read more carefully and realized that it is not in the Sobolev spaces but in the following set I list below.
$W_\alpha = \{ u \in L_{loc}^1 : u \text{ has a weak derivative of order } |\alpha| \}$

By $\delta^\alpha u$ you mean the $\alpha$-th order weak derivative of $u$ right ? This is more commonly denoted $D^\alpha u$. And similarly by $\delta^\alpha u_n \not\to u$ I guess you mean $D^\alpha u_n \not\to D^\alpha u$ ?

Yes, the question is about the weak derivative of the function. I noticed that mistake and corrected it. Thank you for pointing it out
